# may ipaddress.collapse_addresses() collapse for more than 1 bit of the mask?

Tags: python, ip-address, ipv4

Why does:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> print [ip for ip in ipaddress.collapse_addresses([ipaddress.IPv4Network(u'192.0.128.0/24'), ipaddress.IPv4Network(u'192.0.129.0/24')])]
[IPv4Network(u'192.0.128.0/23')]
```

but:

```
>>> print [ip for ip in ipaddress.collapse_addresses([ipaddress.IPv4Network(u'192.0.129.0/24'), ipaddress.IPv4Network(u'192.0.130.0/24')])]
[IPv4Network(u'192.0.129.0/24'), IPv4Network(u'192.0.130.0/24')]
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
>>> print [ip for ip in ipaddress.collapse_addresses([ipaddress.IPv4Network(u'192.0.129.0/24'), ipaddress.IPv4Network(u'192.0.130.0/24')])]
[IPv4Network(u'192.0.128.0/22')]
```

It seems like `collapse_addresses` cannot collapse for more than 1 bit of the mask.

Comment: The function collapse works properly. It will find a mask that covers ALL the IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns the smallest network that contain the ipv4 networks of a list:

```
ADDRESS_ANY = ip_address(u'0.0.0.0')
def one_net(subnets):
    """
    Get the one IP network that covers all subnets in input,
    or None is subnets are disjoint.
    """
    if len(subnets) == 0:
        return None

    minlen = min([net.prefixlen for net in subnets])
    while subnets.count(subnets[0]) < len(subnets) and minlen > 0:
        # all subnets are not (yet) equal
        subnets = [net.supernet(new_prefix=minlen) for net in subnets]
        minlen -= 1

    # 0.0.0.0/? -> no common subnet
    if subnets[0].network_address == ADDRESS_ANY:
        return None
    return subnets[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import ipaddr

ips = [ipaddr.IPv4Address(ip) for ip in ['10.10.10.0','10.10.11.0']]
ips = sorted(ips)
lowest_ip  = ips[0]  #first 
highest_ip = ips[-1] #last 
mask_length = ipaddr._get_prefix_length(int(lowest_ip), int(highest_ip), 
lowest_ip.max_prefixlen)
network_ip = ipaddr.IPNetwork("{}/{}".format(lowest_ip, mask_length)).network
network = ipaddr.IPNetwork("{}/{}".format(network_ip, mask_length), strict = True)
print (network)
```

$> 10.10.10.0/23